# MongoDB Shema to support concurrent update on a document

Tags: database-design, mongodb, schema, nosql, node.js

We were working on a project with a 300 documents with `currentValue` field in a main collection, in order to track the history of each document of first collection. we created another collection named `history` with approximately 6.5 millions of documents.
For each input of system we have to add around 30 history item and update `currentValue` field of main collection, so, We tried computational field design pattern for `currentValue`, which lead us to have `writeConfilict` in concurrent situations (at concurrency of around 1000 requests).

Then we tried to compute `currentValue` field with `sum` (`amount` field) and `groupBy`(`mainId` field) on history collection  which takes too long (> 3s).

Main collection docs:

```javascript
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(...),
    "stock" : [ 
        {
            "currentAmount" : -313430.0,
            "lastPrice" : -10.0,
            "storage" : ObjectId("..."),
            "alarmCapacity" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "currentAmount" : 30,
            "lastPrice" : 0,
            "storage" : ObjectId("..."),
            "alarmCapacity" : 12
        }, 
       .
       .
       .
    ],
    "name" : "name",

}
```

History collection docs:

```javascript
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "mainId" : ObjectId("..."),
    "amount" : 5,
}
```

If you have any other idea to handle this situation(application or db level), I would be thankful.

UPDATE 1

The update query if I use computed pattern would be:

```javascript
mainCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                $and: [
                    { _id: id },
                    { "stock.storage": fromId },
                    { "stock.deletedAt": null }
                ],
            },
            {
                $inc: {
                    "stock.$.currentAmount": -1 * amount,
                }
            },
            {
                session
            }
        )
```

And Aggregation pipeline if I want to calculate `currentAmount` everytime:

```javascript
mainCollection.aggregate([
            {
                $match: { 
                    branch: new ObjectId("...")
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$ingredient",
                    currentAmount: {
                        $sum: "$amount"
                    }
                }
            }])
```